# object is masked by GlobalEnv error

Tags: r, pryr

I have installed package pryr in my R studio and now trying to import the same, using

```
library(pryr)
```

Getting the error as :

```
Attaching package: ‘pryr’

The following object is masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:

    f
```

What shall be done, so that I can import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've successfully loaded pryr. Congratulations!

The message is telling you that you have an object `f` in your global environment. There is also a function called `f` that is exported by pryr. If you try to use this function, you may end up referring to your own `f` instead, causing problems. To disambiguate, you can use `pryr::f` to refer to the `f` in pryr.